# Approximate compare between two vector

Tags: r

I have a two different vectors

```
v1 <- c("HelloWorld", "Climate","fooboo","testtesting")
v2 <- c("hello","test")
```

I want to compare both the vector and need to get **"HelloWorld" and "testingtestin"**.

I used regexpr, but i have'nt get the result.

```
sapply(v1 , regexpr, v2 ,  ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Comment: try `grep(paste(v2, collapse = '|'), v1, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)`

Comment: Or using `sapply` (OPs way): `sapply(v2, grep, v1, value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)`